# A new expression requires () or [] after type c#

Tags: c#

I'm using CodeDom to compile the following code and save as an EXE

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
  {
     TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
     td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

     // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
     td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 1 });

     // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

     // Register the task in the root folder
     ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

     // Remove the task we just created
     ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
  }
}
}
```

The only problem is when I select the save location and compile I get the errro "A new expression requires () or [] after type". I really can't see what I'm missing here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably using C# 2.0

Answer (score 1):

CodeDOM uses the C#2 compiler by default, so your example will not compile. To compile with the C# 3 compiler you can pass an option to the provider on construction:

```
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand where I put that code, is it supposed to go in my compiler class? Sorry if this is a stupid question this is the first time I've used CodeDom and documentation isn't great.

Comment: @user3341661 - You pass the options when you create the provider to do the compilation. You need to find where you're creating the provider now and pass the dictionary of options in the constructor, instead of using the default constructor you're probably using at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This line should fix it:

```
td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger() { DaysInterval = 1 });
```

Next time, put the code into Visual Studio and use the warnings/errors window to find the problem.

Comment: The original will compile in VS, this looks like a CodeDOM issue.